# Symfony DBAL y Azure, doctrine:schema:update siempre me hace actualizaciones en base de datos

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, symfony4, doctrine2

Tengo una aplicación en Symfony 4.4 conectada a una base de datos en Azure. La aplicación en principio va bien, pero siempre que hago un update del schema sea por diff o con --force, me salen ALTER COLUM que no deberían salir. He Leido un poco y parece que esta relacionado con esto:

https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6790

pensé que la actualización se habría arreglado. ¿alguien puede echarme un mano o donde mas buscar?

Answer (score 0):

Me contesto yo mismo, por lo que he visto en la capa de DBAL cuando va contra Azure se toma muy en serio los campos unsigned y default. 
Mi consejo es que los valores por defecto y que sea mayor que 0 se hagan por medio de los controladores de Symfony. No en la base de datos, y que las tablas sean lo mas simples posibles.